# using range for nth child selector - cleaning up some code

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I've managed to simulate a slideshow nested inside tabs - where the next button on the last slide in a tab can take you through to the next tab.

I've done it using nth-child selectors - however ive had to literally punch in a function for each nth child - eg:

```
if (nth-child(1)) {}; 
else if (nth-child(2)) {}; 
else is (nth-child(3)){;
```

etc etc

is there a way to use a range of values for the nth-child selector - something like:

```
 if (nth-child(1-3){};
```

or

```
  if (nth-child(1,2,3){};
```

something like that.

full code is here http:[here](http:////jsfiddle.net/zandergrin/fPvJK/4/)

thanks!

Comment: look at jQuery selector gt, lt and eq

Comment: I tried that, as did the guy below, but it doesn;t seem to work the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!

Use the `index()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/fPvJK/8/

```
var selector = "#tab" + (Math.floor($(this).index()/3)+1);
$("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").removeClass("active");
$(selector).addClass("active");
```

`$(this).index()` is `0-index` according the the place in its `parent`'s `childNode`-tree.

If we say we have the number 3 element in the dom: ( `0-index = 2` )

```
Math.floor(2/3) +1 =
Math.floor(0,67) + 1 =
0 + 1 = 1
```

The selector is then:

```
#tab1
```

and again if we take the 7th element in the dom: `0-index = 6`;

```
Math.floor(6/3) + 1 = 
2 + 1 = 3
```

this would give us

```
var selector = "#tab3";
```

Or we could just just `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.floor + 1` :)

```
var selector = "#tab" + Math.ceil($(this).index()/3);
$("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").removeClass("active");
$(selector).addClass("active");
```

Math.floor rounds down, Math.ceil rounds up, and Math.round round to nearest:

```
Math.floor(2.1); // 2
Math.floor(2.9); // 2

Math.ceil(2.1); // 3
Math.ceil(2.9); // 3

Math.round(2.1); // 2
Math.round(2.9); // 3
```

note: using `round` with `.5` round up.

```
Math.round(2.5) // 3
```

Comment: only thing is - in the 7th element example you've put there's a 2 where there should be a 3 I think (in case anyone needs it in the future)

Comment: yes it would be /5 you can also count the length of the tabs `$("#nav li").length` ... `/$("#nav li").length`

Answer (score 3):

There is also a way to select all items since an index with the following selector :

```
$(':nth-child(n3)').addClass('test');
```

In this example, all items after the second will be affected.

Comment: This is awesome. It selects all elements greater than index three, inclusive.

`$(':nth-child(-n3)');` would select all elements lesser than index three, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

can use [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function -

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fPvJK/11/)**

Example-

```
var index = $(this).index('#slideshow li');
if(index < 3) {
     $('#tab1').addClass('active');
     $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
     $('#tab3').removeClass('active');
}
else if(2 < index && index < 6) {
     $('#tab1').removeClass('active');
     $('#tab2').addClass('active');
     $('#tab3').removeClass('active');
}
else if(index > 5) {
     $('#tab1').removeClass('active');
     $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
     $('#tab3').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: this doesn;t seem to work, your fiddle doesn't work either. the purpose of the active class is to highlight the tabs at the top - which doesn't seem to happen in your demo. Am I missing something?

Comment: lt and gt works only on collection, as this is a single element the tab switching does not work. Update the answer.

Comment: does work brilliantly now, but had to give it to Andreas for a super neat answer. thanks though